# Optional terms in match_phrase elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I am using elasticsearch 6 and have the following query

```
{  
 "query":{  
  "bool":{  
     "should":[  
        {  
           "match_phrase":{  
              "fieldOne":{  
                 "query":"One two three",
                 "slop":10
              }
           }
        },
        {  
           "match_phrase":{  
              "fieldTwo":{  
                 "query":"one two three",
                 "slop":10
              }
           }
        }

     ]
  }
 }
}
```

This works well when I want to match on the two fields with the terms in the query.

However if I have a document which has term 'one' and 'two' in fieldOne the above does not return results as 'three' is required

I cannot seems to find a way of making the terms in the query optional e.g. what I wanted is to say find any of the terms in those two fields

The reason I went with match_phrase is the use of the slop which allows the terms to be in different positions in the field which i also require

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the order is not important to use, you don't need to use `match_phrase`, a simple `match` query does the job

```
    {  
       "match":{  
          "fieldOne":{  
             "query":"one two three"
          }
       }
    },
```

Then if you need at least two terms to match you can do so using [`minimum_should_match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html):

```
    {  
       "match":{  
          "fieldOne":{  
             "query":"one two three",
             "minimum_should_match": 2
          }
       }
    },
```